# Problemas con AJAX y JQuery

Tags: mysql, jquery, ajax

compañeros.

Tengo un problema: Tengo un código JQuery para subir información a una base de datos en MySql. Me sube los datos, pero en ocasiones me crea una especie de loop y me sube los mismos datos muchas veces; en otras ocasiones, no me sube los datos y además, me envía a la página de inicio. Lo mismo ocurre cuando actualizo, o cuando borro los datos a través de la página.

Aquí dejo el código JQuey:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function obtener_datos(){
            $.ajax({                        
                type:"POST",                 
                url:"subir.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#page').html(data);               
                }
            });
        }
        $("#subir").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url="subir_fichas.php";
            var form=$('#formulario')[0];
            var formData=new FormData(form);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:url,
                data:formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    obtener_datos();
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error.");    
                }
    });
        })
        function actualizar_datos(id, texto, columna){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"actualizar.php",
                data:{id:id, texto:texto, columna:columna},
                success:function(data){
                    obtener_datos();
                }
            })
        }
        $(document).on("blur", "#sibol_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("sibol_prod");
            var sibol_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, sibol_producto, "sibol_prod");
            alert(id);
            alert(sibol_producto);
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#nombre_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("nombre_prod");
            var nombre_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, nombre_producto, "nombre_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#categoria_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("categoria_prod");
            var categoria_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, categoria_producto, "categoria_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#calidad_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("calidad_prod");
            var sub_categoria_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, sub_categoria_producto, "calidad_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#generalidades_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("generalidades_prod");
            var generalidades_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, generalidades_producto, "generalidades_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#re_generales_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("re_generales_prod");
            var re_generalidades_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, re_generalidades_producto, "re_generales_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#re_espe_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("re_espe_prod");
            var re_espe_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, re_espe_producto, "re_espe_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#empaque_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("empaque_prod");
            var empaque_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, empaque_producto, "empaque_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("blur", "#presentacion_prod", function(){
            var id=$(this).data("presentacion_prod");
            var presentacion_producto=$(this).text();
            actualizar_datos(id, presentacion_producto, "presentacion_prod");
        })
        $(document).on("click", "#eliminar", function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("¿Estás seguro de eliminar los datos del aprendiz?")) {
                function obtener_datos(){
                    $.ajax({                        
                        type:"POST",                 
                        url:"subir.php",
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#page').html(data);               
                        }
                    });
                }
                var id=$(this).data("eliminar");
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"borrar.php",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        obtener_datos();
                    }
                })
            };
        })
        function cambiar(){
            var pdrs = document.getElementById('file-upload').files[0].name;
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = pdrs;
        }
    });
```

Este código me sube, actualiza y borra datos desde la página web.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. No considero importante subir todas las etiquetas de las tablas HTML5.

Comment: He notado que al haber un primer registro ya ingresado, son los demás los que empiezan a fallar.

Comment: he visto que sube los datos columna por columna, no es mas fácil subir todo de una, ademas con este método lo ubico que va a genera es congestión en la base de datos y mas trabajo

Comment: ¿Me podrías indicar cómo realizaría tu sugerencia? Soy aún un aprendiz.